# How to hide specific option in the drop-down values while combining two drop-downs in Angular

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a *dropdown* named *country*, which has **3 values "India,china, australia"** and I have a *dropdown* named *position* which has **3 values " application developer ,application developer- WW, application developer -GEO".**

I want to **show all 3 values of the second dropdown when country is other than India.**

for **India it should only show application developer**

```
<mat-form-field class="no-bord">
                                            <mat-select [ngClass]="isValidCountry?'sb-push-unread':'sb-push-read'" id="country" tabindex="21" (ngModelChange)="onChangeCountry($event)" name="country_code" [(ngModel)]="requestData.country_code" class="form-control form-control-cust">
                                                <mat-option value="" selected>Select Physical Country</mat-option>
                                                <mat-option *ngFor="let ele of geocountry" [value]="ele.country_id">{{ele.country_name}}</mat-option>
                                            </mat-select>
                                        </mat-form-field>


    <mat-form-field class="no-bord">
                                            <mat-select [ngClass]="isValidjobrole?'sb-push-unread':'sb-push-read'" #offr="ngModel" tabindex="17" class="form-control form-control-cust offering" (ngModelChange)="onChangeJobrole($event)" name="job_role" [(ngModel)]="requestData.job_role">
                                                <mat-option value="" selected>Select Job Role</mat-option>
                                                <mat-option *ngFor="let ele of jobrole" [value]="ele.JOB_ROLE_ID">{{ele.JOB_ROLE_NAME}}</mat-option>
                                            </mat-select>
                                        </mat-form-field>
```

my ts file is below:

onChangeGeo(newgeoindex) {

```
this.requestData.country_code = '';
this.requestData.msc_location = '';
this.nocountry = false;
this.geocountry = [];
this.msccountry = [];
this.msccity = [];
this.isothercity = false;
this.maincity = " ";
this.othercitydata = " ";
for (let geo of this.masterData['geo_country']) {
  if (geo.geo_id == newgeoindex) {
    this.requestData.geo = geo.geo_name;
    this.requestData.geo_code = geo.geo_code;
    this.geocountry = geo.countries;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: why dont you show us some code so that we can modify and answer

Comment: the values are coming from the DB, should i just get you my code?...

Comment: yes, what have you tried ? whats not working ?

Comment: i now have the code for dynamic data, can you let me know if it can be done or do you need more code.

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya can you please see to it once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find working example here 1. (`using RXJS way`) [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y5hncy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You can find working example here 2. (`using simple component way`) [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-93cjn3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You can find working example here 3. (`using pipe`) [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dy9krk?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffilter.pipe.ts)

Above are three different way of doing as per your requirement.

**app.component.html**

```
<select (change)="onSelected($event)">
    <option>select </option>
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">{{country}} </option>
</select>
<hr>
<select>
   <option> select</option>
   <option *ngFor="let dev of developers"> {{dev}} </option>
</select>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
   countries = ['India', 'China', 'Australia', 'USA'];
   developers = ["application developer" ,"application developer- WW", "application developer -GEO"];
   developersCopy = ["application developer" ,"application developer- WW", "application developer -GEO"];
   onSelected(country){
      if (country.target.value === 'India'){
         this.developers = this.developers.filter(val => val.toString() === 'application developer')
   }else{
     this.developers = this.developersCopy;
   }
  }
```

This is very quick, solution for your reference, since you are not going to tell about your approach of doing solution. There are numerous ways to improve this solution.

Comment: hey, this works. what if its just opposite I want to show all options for India and hide for others.

Comment: change condition as per requirement `if (country.target.value !== 'India')` this is opposite of what you are doing before

Comment: hey, what if the countries are dynamic and even the job role.. i have updated my code. do you need anything more to help me out..

Comment: hey, Gaurang I saw you updated the code .. can you tell what more i need to add to make it work if possible

Comment: I have updated example using rxjs and behavior-subject so that you can use as per your requirement

Comment: I did gave a try to another approach too if you can help... can you help me remove the values that has (geo and ww) by running a loop in the dropdown

Comment: as i don't have control on the values, i have to use splice function..

Comment: i could not understand what you are trying to do? Can you explain more bit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208227/discussion-between-jayant-kaushik-and-gaurangdhorda).

Answer (score 0):

one more way

[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-93cjn3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
appcomponent.html

```
<select (change)="onSelected($event)">
  <option value="select"> select </option>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.countryName}} </option>
</select>
<hr>
<select>
  <option> select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let dev of developers"  > {{dev.devName}} </option>
</select>
```

app component.ts

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import {countries, developers} from './model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection : ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(){}
  countries = countries as Array <any>;
  developers : any ;
  onSelected(country){

      return (+country.target.value !== 1 || country.target.value === 'select') ? this.developers = this.developers.filter(val => val.id === 1) : this.developers = developers;
  }
}
```